# Quicktab problem on the argument of view and block

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I used to make a view shows a page of a project in the url:  `projects/[node:author]/[node:nid]`, this view works well.

Now I want to display this view in the quicktab, but the problem is I can't view the content of the view. I think it is because of the configuration of argument of quicktabs. In the quicktabs, I have selected this view and display it as page, but the problem is I am not sure how to config the arguments.

As you have seen the url of view, is `projects/[node:author]/[node:nid]`, in which there are 2 arguments, when I set it as %0/%1, not working, %0/%1/%2, still not working, and set it as projects/%0/%1, not working either.

**Is there any problem with my config?**

Also in the quicktabs, I also display the comments related to that content, previously I made another block with default value as contextual argument like projects/[node:author]/[node:nid], but when I try to put it the quicktabs as a block, it also doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an issue with the quick tabs module. I have the same issue on version 7.x-3.4. It seems to break as soon as you use the % URL variables

**UPDATE**: After looking at the code, the module calls args(), in my case, the values returned from that are different than the URL. For example, my URL is "product/reading" however, quicktabs gets this Array ( [0] => node [1] => 180 ). So I have to change my view to use the node ID instead of the node title. This should have been noted in the modules documentation.